# Chef Command Failing because of old libxml2

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, nokogiri, libxml2, knife

I am trying to setup a Chef Workstation and am getting the below error when I run

```
knife ssl check
```

Error:

```
Library not loaded: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/libxml2.2.dylib 
(LoadError)
  Referenced from: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
  Reason: Incompatible library version: nokogiri.bundle requiresversion 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0 - /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
```

I am new to Chef, but tried installing libxml2 and nokogiri thru brew to fix this.  Did not change the error.

Answer (score 0):

you did not specify how did you install `knife`... i can assume that you installed it by installing [`chef` rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/chef). if so, use `bundle exec knife` to make sure you are running with the rubygems you specified in your `Gemfile`